# Code first migration breaks after changing Default Schema name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So i have this context.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Name");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<EntityA> TableA { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EntityB> TableB{ get; set; }
}
```

Which results in this:

> Name.__MigrationHistory
>
> Name.TableA
>
> Name.TableB

And that is all good.

However then i run

```
Enable-Migrations
Update-Database
```

It gives me

> Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory.

How do i tell it to use the new table with schema "Name"?

`Name.__MigrationHistory` instead of `dbo.__MigrationHistory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `Enable-Migrations` try running `Add-Migration Initial`.

Comment: The problem was that i was using Automatic Migrations. When I disabled it and created an Initial migration it worked.